# How to export swf so the timeline doesn't play...but allows onclick actions?

Tags: flash, embed, dreamweaver

I recently stepped into the shoes of a web designer who was Flash-crazy, and used Dreamweaver's design-View exclusively. I am not familiar with Flash (jQuery all the way), and I write most code from scratch.

So, I'm trying to make small changes to one of her old Flash sites. Since I'm unfamiliar with Flash (and most of Dreamweaver's "functions"), the problem could very well be the way I'm publishing, or it could have something to do with a small script needed in Dreamweaver. I'm not sure.

The whole page (links and sub-windows, etc) is Flash actions. I had to make the page smaller, and make a few minor changes. I "published" my page (Flash + HTML) and make sure all the scripts sync up correctly, and I [get this](http://www.zlotnickconstruction.com/about_team_tst.html).

The timeline is playing like a movie, and I need it not to "play" but just provide the actions for the links and stuff. Like [this](http://www.zlotnickconstruction.com/pages/About_ZlotnickTeam.html) (old site)

Can anyone view the source and see any obvious errors? Or did I miss a step in publishing or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can't work out much from 'view source' when the source is simply embedding the flash movie. Are you creating the SWF from within Flash?

A simple `stop();` on the first line of actionscript of your first frame should stop it playing through as it is.

Comment: Yes, I'm publishing the .swf from an .fla, out of Flash Flash. I do have a feeling my problem is in the published .swf itself (which you obviously wouldn't be able to address via source code), but I thought maybe I might have a script problem in the Dreamweaver file.

Comment: Yes. You should have a layer on the timeline (normally the top one) with an 'a' for actions on the first frame. Control click that and select actions should show you the AS3 that has been written. And add the stop(); as the first line there, and try republishing